# Makefile does not compile the current changes .c file

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing a makefile for my program, but whenever i do make in my pwd, it is not showing with the latest changes made in .c file. What am i doing wrong with this ?

```
web : mweb.o
    gcc -o bin/web bin/web.o 
mweb.o : src/web.c
    gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall src/web.c -o bin/web.o
clean:
    rm -f web
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing"?

Comment: Also your output binary is  `bin/web`, but your `clean` target is deleting it from the current directory, not `bin`

Comment: when i do make, in my pwd, the errors or warnings fixed inside web.c are not updating and showing on terminal

Comment: Your rule to make `mweb.o` builds `bin/web.o`.  But `web` depends on `mweb.o`.  What builds `mweb.o`?

Answer (score 2):

It's always wrong for your makefile rules to create files that are not the identical pathname of the target you provided in your rule.  So:

```
<target>: ...
        <command>
```

The `<command>` must create the file named by `<target>`.

Here, your `<target>` in the first rule is `web`, but the compile command you gave creates the file `bin/web`.  Your `<target>` on the second rule is `mweb.o` but the compile command creates the file `bin/web.o`.

That cannot work.

The best thing to do is use make's `$@` [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html): those are set by make and always contain the files that make expects you to create.

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall

bin/web : bin/mweb.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 
bin/mweb.o : src/web.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean:
        rm -f web
```